# Subsetting in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've been working on a visualization project in shiny. I'm trying to filter a data set by given input - number of state and range of the slider. Unfortunately, r 'omits' the the code part and outputs the entire data set. I also get warnings: 'data' is not a graphical parameter.

```
library(shiny)
library(Ecdat)


u <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Social benefits"),
  sidebarPanel(

    selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                list("Unemployment", 
                     "Max benefit" 
               )),
    #Specification of state
    textInput("state", "State:", value = "93"),
    # Specification of range within an interval
    sliderInput("range", "Range:",
                min = 1, max = 100, value = c(20,100))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("mpgPlot")
  )

))

s <- shinyServer(function(input, output) 
{
  #filter by state -ERROR
  p <- reactive({ Benefits[Benefits$state == input$state,]})

  #filter by slider range - ERROR
  dataX <- reactive({ p()[input$range[1]:input$range[2],,drop = FALSE] })

  variable <- reactive({
    switch(input$variable,
           "Unemployment" = stateur,
           "Max benefit" = statemb
           )
    })

  caption <- reactive({
    paste(input$variable)
  })

  output$mpgPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(variable(), data = dataX(), type = "l",ylab = caption())
  })

})
shinyApp(u,s)
```

Comment: Why do you have the `()` after the P in the `dataX ,-` line?  Also don't call something var since it is the name of a function.  What do you mean by plot(var()?

Comment: I always use brackets after a variable defined by 'reactive' , in this case subset of a subset. Plot(var()) - plots time serie of a selected variable.

Comment: Where are  `stateur` and `statemb` (used in lines 35 & 36) defines?

Comment: stateur - state unemploy. rate statemb - state max. benefit - variables from the data set

Comment: var() will try to compute a variance.

Comment: Already changed to variable(), but there's no difference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was actually needed was to specify the data set name before the variable, since the data set from the environment was overshadowing the filtered one.

```
output$urPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(dataX()$stateur, data = dataX(), type = "l",ylab = "Unemployment")
  })
  output$mbPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(dataX()$statemb, data = dataX(), type = "l",ylab = "Max benefit")
  })
```